# Neo4j: Display reqursive query result as path elements from Neo4JTemplate

Tags: java, json, neo4j

I have the following node structure `Employee[e_id, e_name, e_bossid]`.
What is more  I have a query that exploit the database in recursive traversal on SELF relation `e_bossid-[REPORTS_TO]->e_id`:

```
// Mark the root (aka `e_bossid IS NULL`)
MATCH (e:Employee) WHERE NOT (e)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()
SET e:Root

// find all paths of arbitrary length from he root
MATCH path = (b:Root)<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-(e:Employee)
RETURN path
limit 1000
```

Now when I use the `Result` like this:

```
Result<Map<String, Object>> result = neo4jTemplate.query(query, null);

    List<Map<String, Object>> table = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> row = null;

    for(Object u : result.to(Object.class)) {

        row = new HashMap<>();
        row.put("neo_eb_id",        u);

        table.add(row);

    }
```

it actually returns only results in form of path JSON representation

```
e_id": {

    "path": {
        "length": 1,
        "start": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
        "relationships": [
            "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/6"
        ],
        "end": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10",
        "nodes": [
            "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
            "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/10"
        ]
    }

},
```

What I need is to get all actual nodes properties in tree structure, not just the paths.
So this is what I am after:

```
node1
  |- node100 (id,name, bossid)
  |     |- node1000 (id, name, bossid)
  |     |- node2000 (id, name, bossid)
  |           |- node2001 (id, name, bossid)
  |           |- node2002 (id, name, bossid)
...
node2

  |- node1001 (id, name, bossid)
```

And I want the node properties to be fetched so it would look like this:

```
e_id: 1
e_name: Johnson
e_bossid:null
path:{
           e_id:10
           e_name:Marks
           e_bossid:1
           path:{
                e_id:100
                e_name: Doe
                e_bossid: 10
           }

}
e_id: 101
e_name: Jinx
e_bossid:{
            e_id:
}
...
```

**1.What would be the fastest Java code - for this simple 3elem node structure - to put the result of this query as a JSON REST response in form of embedded node tree structure with all of the node properties values?**

**2. Is there a better or neo4j way to achieve such result?**

Comment: try to use result.to(Path.class) and the use the Path's operation like `length(), nodes()` etc. to build up your tree as nested maps and lists